# Callback not being raised for an overloaded mocked method

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-identity, moq, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm building a multi-tenant website, and so I need to overload `UserManager.CreateAsync()` to accept an additional parameter of type `City`. In other words, each `User` belongs to a `City`. I've configured extra properties on the `User` model accordingly.

The trouble is that I can't get Moq to raise the callback for the overloaded mocked method.

Here's my mock setup:

```vb
Protected Function GetUserManagerMock(Of TUser As Db.User)(Users As List(Of TUser), ExpectedResult As IdentityResult) As Mock(Of UserManager)
  Dim oCreateSetup As Expression(Of Func(Of UserManager, Task(Of IdentityResult)))
  Dim oDeleteSetup As Expression(Of Func(Of UserManager, Task(Of IdentityResult)))
  Dim oUpdateSetup As Expression(Of Func(Of UserManager, Task(Of IdentityResult)))
  Dim oManagerMock As Mock(Of UserManager)
  Dim oStoreMock As Mock(Of IUserStore(Of TUser))
  Dim oCallback As Action(Of TUser, String, Db.City)
  Dim oManager As UserManager
  Dim oResult As IdentityResult

  oStoreMock = New Mock(Of IUserStore(Of TUser))
  oManagerMock = New Mock(Of UserManager)(oStoreMock.Object)
  oManager = oManagerMock.Object
  oCallback = Sub(User, Password, City)
                oResult = oManager.PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(Password).Result

                If oResult Is IdentityResult.Success Then
                  User.PasswordHash = oManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(Password)
                  Users.Add(User)

                  User.CityId = City.Id
                  User.City = City

                  City.Users.Add(User)
                End If
              End Sub

  oCreateSetup = Function(Manager) Manager.CreateAsync(It.IsAny(Of TUser), It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of Db.City))
  oDeleteSetup = Function(Manager) Manager.DeleteAsync(It.IsAny(Of TUser))
  oUpdateSetup = Function(Manager) Manager.UpdateAsync(It.IsAny(Of TUser))

  oManagerMock.Setup(oCreateSetup).ReturnsAsync(ExpectedResult).Callback(oCallback)
  oManagerMock.Setup(oDeleteSetup).ReturnsAsync(ExpectedResult)
  oManagerMock.Setup(oUpdateSetup).ReturnsAsync(ExpectedResult)

  Return oManagerMock
End Function
```

Here's the overloaded `UserManager` method:

```vb
Public Overridable Overloads Async Function CreateAsync(User As Db.User, Password As String, City As Db.City) As Task(Of IdentityResult)
  Dim oResult As IdentityResult

  Password.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(Password))
  User.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(User))
  City.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(City))

  User.CityId = City.Id
  User.City = City

  oResult = Await MyBase.CreateAsync(User, Password)

  If oResult.Succeeded Then
    City.Users.RemoveAll(Function(U) U.Id = User.Id)
    City.Users.Add(User)
  Else
    User.CityId = Nothing
    User.City = Nothing
  End If

  Return oResult
End Function
```

Here's the controller method under test:

```vb
<HttpPost>
<ActionName("Create")>
<AllowAnonymous>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
Public Async Function CreateAsync(Model As Welcome) As Task(Of ActionResult)
  Dim oIdentity As IdentityResult
  Dim oAction As ActionResult
  Dim oUser As Db.User

  If Me.ModelState.IsValid Then
    If Model.City.IsNothing Then
      Model.City = Me.TempData.Peek(NameOf(Db.City))
      oAction = Me.View("One", Model)
    Else
      oUser = New Db.User With {
        .FirstName = Model.FirstName,
        .LastName = Model.LastName,
        .UserName = Model.Username,
        .CityId = Model.City.Id,
        .City = Model.City
      }

      oIdentity = Await Me.UserManager.CreateAsync(oUser, Model.Password, Model.City)

      If oIdentity.Succeeded Then
        oAction = Me.View("Two", Model)
      Else
        oAction = Me.View("Three", Model)
      End If
    End If
  Else
    oAction = Me.View("Four", Model)
  End If

  Return oAction
End Function
```

...and here's the test:

```vb
<Fact>
Public Async Function CreateUserSucceeds() As Task
  Dim oUserManager As UserManager
  Dim oController As UsersController
  Dim oViewModel As Welcome
  Dim oResult As ViewResult
  Dim oCity As Db.City

  Me.Users.Clear()
  Me.Cities.ForEach(Sub(City) City.Users.Clear())

  oCity = Me.Cities.First
  oUserManager = Me.UserManagerMock(Me.Users, IdentityResult.Success).Object
  oController = New UsersController(Me.Worker, Nothing, oUserManager, Nothing)
  oViewModel = New Welcome With {.City = oCity, .FirstName = "User", .LastName = "Name", .Password = "P@ssw0rd!"}
  oResult = TryCast(Await oController.CreateAsync(oViewModel), ViewResult)

  Assert.True(Me.Users.Count = 1)
  Assert.True(Me.Users.First.City.IsNotNothing)
  Assert.True(oCity.Code = Me.Users.First.City.Code)
End Function
```

Execution skips the overloaded `UserManager.CreateAsync()` method as expected, but the callback `Action` never runs. This line of code from the controller method seems to be skipped entirely:

```vb
oIdentity = Await Me.UserManager.CreateAsync(oUser, Model.Password, Model.City)
```

Thus `oIdentity` is `Nothing` (`null` in C#), no matter what I do.

I tried creating the mock with `CallBase` turned on, like so:

```vb
oManagerMock = New Mock(Of UserManager)(oStoreMock.Object) With {.CallBase = True}
```

...but that resulted in the overloaded method itself being run, which of course won't do. I'm running unit tests, not integration tests.

Can anyone spot why this callback isn't being called?

**--EDIT 1--**

I've since discovered that the callback is no longer raised for *any* method that I mock—not just the overloaded method. This is exceedingly odd, as it was working in the past.

I've determined to restore the code from backup and return it to its working state. I'll have more information soon.

**--EDIT 2--**

The problem remains unsolved, but I've gotten a bit closer.

The callback is raised successfully when I cast the `UserManager` for the mock to the Identity framework class (i.e. `UserManager(Of TUser)`). However, when I cast it to my subclass, in order to get the overloaded method, it fails.

This is why I was initially under the impression that only the overloaded method was causing the failure—because I had to change the casting in order to be able to mock that method. The casting change had caused the problem, not the overload.

I've examined [the source code for the Identity framework](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/a7f170d47dd1bb0fa300a15cb0fa8b42a9420e9e/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserManager.cs#L451), and I'm not spotting anything that's different in concept from mine.

Here's my full `UserManager` subclass:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Intexx
Imports Website.Models
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection

Public Class UserManager
  Inherits UserManager(Of Db.User)

  Public Sub New(Store As IUserStore(Of Db.User))
    MyBase.New(Store)

    Me.PasswordValidator = New PasswordValidator
    Me.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Me)
  End Sub

  Public Shared Function Create(Options As IdentityFactoryOptions(Of UserManager), Context As IOwinContext) As UserManager
    Dim oPhoneProvider As PhoneNumberTokenProvider(Of Db.User)
    Dim oEmailProvider As EmailTokenProvider(Of Db.User)
    Dim oDataProtector As IDataProtector
    Dim oDataProvider As IDataProtectionProvider
    Dim oUserStore As IUserStore(Of Db.User)
    Dim oManager As UserManager
    Dim oContext As Db.Context

    oContext = Context.Get(Of Db.Context)
    oUserStore = New UserStore(Of Db.User)(oContext)

    oManager = New UserManager(oUserStore) With {
      .MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5,
      .DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
      .UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = True
    }

    ' Create the two-factor authentication providers
    oPhoneProvider = New PhoneNumberTokenProvider(Of Db.User) With {.MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"}
    oEmailProvider = New EmailTokenProvider(Of Db.User) With {.Subject = "Security Code", .BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"}

    ' Register the two-factor authentication providers. This application
    ' uses Phone and Email as a step of receiving a code for verifying
    ' the user. You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
    oManager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", oPhoneProvider)
    oManager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", oEmailProvider)

    oDataProvider = Options.DataProtectionProvider

    If oDataProvider.IsNotNothing Then
      oDataProtector = oDataProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity")
      oManager.UserTokenProvider = New DataProtectorTokenProvider(Of Db.User)(oDataProtector)
    End If

    oManager.EmailService = New EmailService
    oManager.SmsService = New SmsService

    Return oManager
  End Function

  Public Overridable Overloads Async Function CreateAsync(User As Db.User, Password As String, City As Db.City) As Task(Of IdentityResult)
    Dim oResult As IdentityResult

    Password.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(Password))
    User.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(User))
    City.ThrowIfNothing(NameOf(City))

    User.CityId = City.Id
    User.City = City

    oResult = Await MyBase.CreateAsync(User, Password)

    If oResult.Succeeded Then
      City.Users.RemoveAll(Function(U) U.Id = User.Id)
      City.Users.Add(User)
    Else
      User.CityId = Nothing
      User.City = Nothing
    End If

    Return oResult
  End Function
End Class
```

For the present, since I seem to be able to raise the callback only when using the native cast, a temporary workaround could be to use that cast and check for `User.City = Nothing` in the callback. At least I could unblock with that.

But for the long run, and for better code stability, I'd like to figure out why the callback isn't raised when I cast `UserManager` to my subclass.

Any ideas? It's a longshot, I know, but could this be a bug in Moq?

**--EDIT 3--**

Actually, it looks to be a bug in VB. It works fine in C#.

Here's a repro solution: [OneDrive](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AodXF_j3BiWkheUQBVvdC3LHzizjAw)

I've [raised an issue at the Moq repo](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/1067), where I've provided some detail on how to use and debug the repro to get the same results.

Due to this new discovery, I'm adding both the VB.NET and C# tags to this question.

Can anyone spot any differences between the two projects?

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You've posted a **lot** of code. Please reduce it down to the minimum required to reproduce the problem. You can gut out a lot of what you've posted.

Comment: I hear you. Actually, though, the minimum required to reproduce the problem involves even more than what is shown here. The best way to see the pared-down code is to download the working repro solution, which contains both a VB.NET and a C# project.

Comment: I'm **not** going to download and run someone else's code on my machine :)

Comment: Oh. Well, I see your point. We're kind of stuck, aren't we?

Comment: Even after you've examined it for safety?

Comment: "Even after you've examined it for safety?" - that's going to take me a good chunk of my time - and my time is valuable (life is short!). Now, if you were paying me - or if this was for a project to cure cancer or eliminate poverty, that'd be different... Ultimately the **onus is on you** to help-me-help-you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222843/discussion-between-intexx-and-dai).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be some sloppiness in the VB.NET compiler which Moq didn't anticipate having to account for.

https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/1067#issuecomment-706671833

It's been adjusted accordingly, which will be available in an upcoming release.

Many thanks to [`stakx`](https://github.com/stakx) for his excellent and speedy work on this.

Comment: My experience is that the additional conversion expressions aren't necessarily added universally (I have a comment in some code that strips out a conversion for properties that mentions something about "if the expression type is given as `Object` rather than `TValue`" which I no longer remember exactly how it would be so done).

Comment: Maybe it is, the purpose is to get at property getters/setters in a type-safe way.  When I originally tried it in both C# and VB, I found that VB had an extra unary conversion included in the expression tree (but I don't remember exactly how I used it that this occurred).  I could probably do it without the expression gymnastics and still get compile-time validity checking using `NameOf` with runtime reflection lookup, but I may have started writing the material in VS 2013 where `NameOf` didn't exist yet.

Comment: I originally got the idea from a write-up on NHibernate, here: http://www.jagregory.com/writings/introduction-to-static-reflection .  It was written over ten years ago, before `NameOf`, which would largely address the static-checking concern with string-based lookups.

Comment: Oh my! I can think of all *kinds* of uses for that :-)

Comment: It's cool, but in VB, the syntax ends up being a little ugly as your code gets littered with `Function(x) x.SomeProperty` vs. the somewhat more elegant `x => x.SomeProperty` in C#.  As I recall, it's advisable, if you do something like this, to set up delegates up-front instead of repeatedly invoking through a stored `PropertyInfo` instance.

Comment: *"set up delegates up-front"* Sounds like good advice. Thanks for the info.